# How to remove inactive games without resigning?

Tags: words-with-friends

I have a feeling some one has hacked several accounts. Initially, I accepted the games (7 different players). When they tried to chat & I didn't respond & they stopped playing. Now it's over 180 days since they last played & it's still showing their turn. The only way I can get them to go away is resigning. Any thoughts?